# Brownian motion first hitting time for $0$

Tags: probability-theory

Let's say that I have a family $(X_t)_{t\in [0, \infty)}$ that is continuous in t everywhere.  (I do not mean almost everywhere, because then there'd be funny but perhaps easily resolved measure theory issues.  You can imagine, if you want, that we are working on the space of continuous paths with Wiener measure, but I think the following claim must be true with only a continuous family of RVs.)

The function

$T_0:=inf\{t>0:X_t=0\}$

is measurable. (Why?)

Progress so far: I can see the analogous claims for when the "=" is replaced by ">" or "<"  There, the rational coordinates are enough.  I struggle to see an expression in terms of countable operations for this $T_0$ though.

Comment: Hint:  If $X_t$ is continuous then $t>T_0$ if and only if for every $N\in\mathbb N$ there exists a rational $s<t$ such that $\|X_s\|<\frac 1N$.

Comment: Ah!  That's the trick.  Use the fact that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.  Thanks!

Comment: Replace $t\gt T_0$ by $t\geqslant T_0$ in the hint.

Comment: Good point well made. (But I can't edit hints.)